# Laravel 5 - constraining by parent relations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Say I have a `reservations` table

```
id - restaurant_table_id - guest_id
1  - 3                   - 5
2  - 4                   - 7
```

And then an `orders` table

```
id - reservation_id - item_id
1  - 1                   - 2
2  - 2                   - 4
```

How can I pull orders that belong to a restaurant table?

I have tried:

```
$orders = ReservationOrders::with(['reservation' => function ($query) use ($restaurant_table_id) {
        $query->where('restaurant_table_id', $restaurant_table_id);
    }])
        ->get();
```

But the results included orders for all restaurant tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter on relation's attributes using Eloquent's **whereHas()** method - you can get more information here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

In your case sth like the code below should help:

```
$orders = ReservationOrders::with('reservation')->whereHas('reservation', function($query) use($restaurant_table_id) {
  $query->where('restaurant_table_id', $restaurant_table_id);
})->get();
```